# mile distance around each feature ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, distance

I have a school layer information and a route map layer. In ArcMap, how can I show the x mile distance around each school base on route information.

I did some research and I found different approaches such as Network Analysis tool, Proximity Tool, Buffer Geo-processing tool,... .

I am not sure what approach I need to use.

Comment: Do you have the Network Analyst Extension?

Comment: No I don't, Is there anyway I can get the similar information available for San Francisco and France in Tutorial folder of ArcGIS , for Ontario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [service areas solver in network Analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_5_Calculating_service_areas_and_creating_an_OD_cost_matrix/004700000060000000/)

If you do a few of them at different intervals then you would be able to show rings of route distance/time from each school along the route layer.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I need to create new "Service Area layer", Am I right? How can I create one for Ontario?

Comment: Yes, You will need a Service Area Layer to start. Generally service areas will be associated with a single point (or point FC) so I'm not sure how you would make one for the entire province. [This Guide](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000048000000) should tell you everything you need.

Comment: Hmmm yes it seems that stack exchange doesn't like that link, it's a Esri video that you can search for on their site, the video is called "Network Analyst - An Introduction" 

http://video.arcgis.com/watch/92/network-analyst-_dash_-an-introduction